# Draw perpendicular line from starting point of Line

Tags: math, line

How to draw a perpendicular line at starting point of a line.. for example a starts at coordinate (x,y) and ends at (x1,y1). I need to draw perpendicular line from point (x,y).

Comment: As a note, if the direction vector of a line is `(ex,ey)` the its perpendicular direction vector is `(-ey,ex)`.

Answer (score 3):

Draw from (x,y)->(x+(y1-y),y-(x1-x))
or (x,y)->(x-(y1-y),y+(x1-x))

Comment: It definitely should. Line rotated 90 degrees left from (0,0)->(x,y)  is (0,0)->(-y,x). What is your aspect ratio?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake.i misplaced the x values.. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user1770377: in stack overflow valuable contribution is best thanked by 'accept' and or 'vote up'...

Comment: Is there an easy way to change the length of the line (but keep the original line the length is was).

Comment: The scaled perpendicular line would be to `x-s*(y1-y), y+s*(x1-x)`, where s is a scaling factor. `s=1/sqrt((x1-x)*(x1-x)+(y1-y)*(y1-y));` would normalize the perpendicular length to 1.